# Why is Rails is trying to rerun migrations on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

On my server when deploying the app for the first time, I ran `rake db:setup` which loads my entire migration history from `schema.rb`. Now I have more stuff I want to add, but when I run `rake db:migrate` on my server I realize it's trying to run my very first migration, which is failing since the table obviously exists.

Examining the `schema_migrations` table on my production server, I realize it only has one entry in it, which is the migration that was the most current at the time of the initial deployment. Isn't it supposed to have the *entire* migration history in it? If so, what caused this? If not, why is it doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how this happened, but the problem was indeed the fact that the `schema_migrations` table only contained the timestamp of the most recent migration as opposed to the full history. I manually inserted all of them and it worked fine.

What scares me is that this somehow happened and I don't know how. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to migrate within the production environment?

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`